# How to extract, calculate, and return numbers in messy text?

Tags: regex, sas

This is a faster question.
There is a messy text which is the definition of Table name, all I want is to get every table number plus 15.

I think perl regular expression or left value `substr()` function may helps but I am not so skillful to solve it.

And I'll give the following example:

```
data test;
    input x $300. @@;
    datalines4;
    %let Tit_Tab5_15    =%NRSTR(Tab5-15 Cross-tabulation of blood routine results(SS) );
    %let Tit_Tab5_16    =%NRSTR(Tab5-16 Cross-tabulation of urine routine results(SS) );
    %let Tit_Tab5_17    =%NRSTR(Tab5-17 Cross-tabulation of blood chemistry results(SS) );
    %let Tit_Tab5_18    =%NRSTR(Tab5-18 Cross-tabulation of electrolyte results(SS) );
    %let Tit_Tab5_19    =%NRSTR(Tab5-19 Cross-tabulation of coagulation results(SS) );
    %let Tit_Tab5_20    =%NRSTR(Tab5-20 Cross-tabulation of blood lipid results(SS) );
;;;;
run;
```

The output should be:

```
%let Tit_Tab5_30    =%NRSTR(Tab5-30 Cross-tabulation of blood routine results(SS) );
%let Tit_Tab5_31    =%NRSTR(Tab5-31 Cross-tabulation of urine routine results(SS) );
%let Tit_Tab5_32    =%NRSTR(Tab5-32 Cross-tabulation of blood chemistry results(SS) );
%let Tit_Tab5_33    =%NRSTR(Tab5-33 Cross-tabulation of electrolyte results(SS) );
%let Tit_Tab5_34    =%NRSTR(Tab5-34 Cross-tabulation of coagulation results(SS) );
%let Tit_Tab5_35    =%NRSTR(Tab5-35 Cross-tabulation of blood lipid results(SS) );
```

Please note that the number of section(the number immediately following word `Tab`) should not change.

Solutions without using `prx` family functions are welcomed, too.

Comment: I don't know SAS but in general you would want to match these lines capturing their content in three capturing groups "before-number", "number" and "after-number". In the environment from which you run the regex you would then perform the addition and a replace with the concatenation of the content of the first capturing group, the calculated number and the content of the third capturing group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prxchange and tranwrd.

```
data want;
   set test;
   _x=tranwrd(x,strip(prxchange('s/.*(?<=\_)((\d+)).*/$1/',1,x)),strip(prxchange('s/.*(?<=\_)((\d+)).*/$1/',1,x)+15));
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may get some idea from this.

```
(%.*?-)(\d+)(.*;)



 Match 1
1.  %let Tit_Tab5_15 =%NRSTR(Tab5-
2.  15
3.  Cross-tabulation of blood routine results(SS) );
Match 2
1.  %let Tit_Tab5_16 =%NRSTR(Tab5-
2.  16
3.  Cross-tabulation of urine routine results(SS) );
Match 3
1.  %let Tit_Tab5_17 =%NRSTR(Tab5-
2.  17
3.  Cross-tabulation of blood chemistry results(SS) );
Match 4
1.  %let Tit_Tab5_18 =%NRSTR(Tab5-
2.  18
3.  Cross-tabulation of electrolyte results(SS) );
Match 5
1.  %let Tit_Tab5_19 =%NRSTR(Tab5-
2.  19
3.  Cross-tabulation of coagulation results(SS) );
Match 6
1.  %let Tit_Tab5_20 =%NRSTR(Tab5-
2.  20
3.  Cross-tabulation of blood lipid results(SS) );
```

Get the group 2 value in every match add '15' then replace it.

https://rubular.com/r/HPQAetIFcfGOHD

Comment: I nearly missed it too, but OP wants to apply arithmetics on those lines ("every table number plus 15")

Comment: Sorry, your code dose not generate my desired output.